# Onclick remove cookie and refresh current page

Tags: jquery, cookies, shopping-cart, business-catalyst

I'm trying to remove 'CartID' cookie when a user clicks a "Clear Cart" link.

So far i have the following from research:

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
</head> 

<body>
   <script>
      $.removeCookie("CartID");
   </script>
</body
```

Can someone help with this. How would i implement a link to remove this cookie so that the cart is cleared and the page refreshes. I'm using Business catalyst and want to place the link in a sidebar site-wide.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your link looks like:

```
<a href="#" id="clear-cart">Clear Cart</a>
```

you can do it like this:

```
$("#clear-cart").click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.removeCookie("CartID");
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks for this. Works great.